# Hiding hamburger menu icon in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am usin MaterialDesignLite to create the navigation layout with the hamburger menu icon. But I need to hide it if user is logged out. But for some reason it is not hiding if I do it inside jquery but is hiding if I do it directly in css.

This is working:

```
.mdl-layout__drawer-button{
display: none;
}
```

This is not working:

```
$(".mdl-layout__drawer-button").hide();
```

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/3ykk7yse/) is JSFiddle

Comment: can you implement this in http://jsfiddle.net . Then provide the result here.

Comment: @AkhterAlaminFarhan updated.

Comment: These is no `.mdl-layout__drawer-button` element in your example!

Comment: He had appended a css file named "material.teal-indigo.min.css". There the div class has been defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `material.teal-indigo.min.css` file, you will search for "mdl-layout__drawer-button", you will find where the property has been defined. Make display 'block' to 'none'. Since the property defined there are important, you can't override the property.

Comment: That did it. Thank you. And if I want to display it, I just say `display: block;` ?

Comment: actually I prefer you to remove "mdl-layout__drawer-button" property from the css file to your customized css file. Then you can customize the property according to your will.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try

$(".mdl-layout__drawer-button").css("display", "none");

Comment: In your jsfiddle I can't find the "mdl-layout__drawer-button". Maybe you are using the wrong object?

Answer (score 0):

Change your

```
$(document).load
```

to

```
$(document).ready
```